# How do I mention the path of an excel file in my VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

How do i mention the path of my excel file in my vba? The thing Im trying to do is, I have to copy the excel file contents to the end of another excel file. I have selected all the cells of excel file and copied like these

```
This is my excelfile1.xlsx
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

Now after copying the whole file I have to paste it to the end of another excel file located at `D:\samples\excel2.xls`

How do I mention the path of these file in VBA and paste to its end from my VBA code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you record this step of actions, you will get almost the exact same code that would result from writing it manually;

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="d:\samples\excel2.xls"
Range("Al").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```